# Correctly Downloading JSON Response As A File

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting `json` response against an endpoint. I need to be able to download that as a json file. Which I am able to do. This downloaded `json` file has to be uploaded against some other endpoint.

**PROBLEM**

I have tested both the download & upload API's using Postman. File downloaded using `Postman` when uploaded gives me the expected response. Which means API is working fine.

**source.js**

```
      const filename = response.headers["content-disposition"].split(
        "filename="
      )[1];

      const data = filename.endsWith(".json")
        ? JSON.stringify(response.data)
        : response.data;

      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data]));
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = url;
      link.setAttribute("download", filename);

      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
```

But the file downloaded using the front-end is when uploaded doesn't work as expected. Which means that this method of downloading the file is somehow not downloading it correctly.

Am I downloading it correctly?

Comment: Did you find out what the difference is between the two files? I.e. diff them...

Comment: Have you checked for cors issues? Check the console

Comment: @marekful checked. No difference.

Comment: If there is no difference between the working one and the not working one what exactly isnt working

Comment: No difference, no problem! If one upload succeeds and the next fails, then there was a difference.... Did you diff NOT ignoring white space? What about headers, URI, path, etc?